My exe file made by auto-py-to-exe has a missing optional dependency "openpyxl"
I made a exe file by auto-py-to-exe.
When I execute the exe this causes this error:

Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.

I tried install and update openpyxl but same error again.

To fix this in the UI, open the advanced tab and find the --hidden-import input.
Simply paste the module name into this input and then repackage.
If the original error is still appearing, you have done this incorrectly.

For example, if you are missing pandas._libs.tslib, add 'pandas._libs.tslib' into 
the input by --hidden-import. Additionally, you can add more than one module, 
for example, pandas._libs.tslib, win32api. 
(See the question mark by the input for more information).

Alternatively, you may have installed auto-py-to-exe in one Python environment 
(a single installation or venv) and installed your dependent package in a different 
Python environment.


Source

